# Polymer 1.0 dom-if template removes display from inner div style

Tags: polymer-1.0

Please consider following planks:

http://embed.plnkr.co/O3xz1m/preview

http://embed.plnkr.co/Ajh2Nm/preview

The first one displays xxx in the center of the screen (in chrome only) whereas the second displays xxx uncentered. Looks like this happens because of

```
<template is="dom-if" if="true">
```

in the second example. As far as I understand  display: flex is just somehow gets removed from the effective page. Why?

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `dom-if` [hides its contents](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if) when `if` becomes falsy as a performance optimization.  It achieves this by setting `style.display = 'none'` on the stamped children.  It currently does not save the previous value of display, so it gets set back to `''` on truthy, hence the previous `flex` value is lost;  We will plan on fixing that behavior against the issue you opened here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2037.

In the meantime, you can either

1. use a class (as opposed to inline style) to apply the `display: flex` on immediate children of the template, or
2. use the `restamp` attribute on `dom-if` to avoid the hiding behavior (has other tradeoffs re: performance that you can read in the `dom-if` docs linked above).